# OpenLayers 3 (3.8.2) How to set a blank Basemap?

Tags: openstreetmap, openlayers, basemap

I want to add a blank (empty) base map option to the set of radio button .

Here is how a part of my code looks:

```
// MapQuest streets
new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: 'Street Map',
  group: "background",
  source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'osm'})
}),
// MapQuest imagery
new ol.layer.Tile({
  title: 'Aerial Imagery',
  group: "background",
  visible: false,
  source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
}),
// MapQuest hybrid (uses a layer group)
new ol.layer.Group({
  title: 'Imagery with Streets',
  group: "background",
  visible: false,
  layers: [
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
    }),
    new ol.layer.Tile({
      source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'hyb'})
    })
  ]
}),
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found this example that is the can be modified to set the blank base map in open layer 3

http://openlayers.org/en/v3.7.0/examples/lazy-source.html

Answer (score 2):

You can create an empty (completely transparent) image and provide it as the URL to a XYZ tile source:

```
new ol.layer.Tile({
    source: new ol.source.XYZ({
       url: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVQIHWNgYGD4DwABBAEAHnOcQAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
    })
})
```

Comment: I guess that would work but i am wondering is there any official solutions ?

Comment: instead of the fake XYZ source, you can simply set source to NULL!